# WSO2 API Manager User Management APIs

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Does the WSO2 API Manager provide APIs for user registration and management?

To be more specific, the documentation states that the user can sign up using the *store* interface. Is there also an equivalent API that I can use to:

- register new users
- to authentication existing users
- to initiate password recoveries

Please add the *wso2am* tag to this question (see [related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640986/wso2-api-manager-user-management-apis#comment25737451_17640986)).

Comment: I see that the tag *wso2apimanager* is getting added and removed many times. IMO a new tag *wso2am* should be added to this question (this tag would match existing tags such as *wso2is*, *wso2esb*, *wso2dss*). And there are dozens of questions that would make good use of this tag: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wso2+api+manager (I can't create this tag because 1k rep is needed). -- I am adding a request for tagging on behalf of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94281/why-cannot-less-than-1500-users-suggest-new-tags/94310#94310

Answer (score 3):

Apart from managing users through the product's Management Console, every carbon server also exposes its management services as web services.

As far as user management is concerned, you can find API samples at the following links (note that these might be specific to work on a particular carbon version):

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/wso2-samples/user-manager/user-admin-client/
http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html

Comment: The second link refers to WSO2 Identity Server: does this work with WSO2 API Manager as well?

Comment: I'd say it should work with all wso2 products, since they share the same wso2 carbon base, acting as some general purpose middleware server. Carbon is able to expose web services for several server management functions, such as user management, shared among all products.

This [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17641479/2198568) seems to be specific to the API manager store app, could be enough to suit your needs for this use case.

Comment: I need also to set custom fields value that are not provided by the standard Store API, I'll probably need to dig more into the *blog.facilelogin.com* article because I see that they set there custom properties.

Comment: Did you continue the user management API in the wso2 api manager or wso2 identity? What i have in my mind is to profiler into database,get the sql query whenever it go into the sign up action.Actually i try not to have too many servers, WSO2 api manager, WSO2 identity, it seems annoying.Somemore I'm not a java developer. Why can't it like konghq, one server to control all the thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, API Store has an exposed API which can be used to register new users (User Signup) and authenticate users ([Login](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Store+APIs)).

**SignUp**

```
curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/ajax/user-add.jag -d "action=addUser&username=user2&password=xxx&allFieldsValues="
```

(Above allFieldsValues will be | seperated values for user fields, firstname, lastname, email, etc. ex :allFieldsValues=lakmali|erandi|lakmali@abc.com)

**Login**

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=user1&password=xxx'
```

But password recovery functionality is not available yet. It will be avilable in future releases.

Comment: Is there a way to customize the additional fields? What are the differences between these REST APIs and the APIs sent by Corso?

Comment: What you meant by additional fields? Did you mean the user claims? Underline the Store APIs I have pointed, the same web service APIs available in carbon are invoked. The store APIs makes it easier because it adds required roles (subscriber role) to the new users, in order to login afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I mean user claims.

Comment: It is possible to customize fields. But in API Manager we don't ship claim management features. If you check this in WSO2 Identity Server, there you can see in Configure->Claim Management, you have the ability to mange cliam dialects by adding new claims, changing order, etc. The claim dialect used in Sign up is http://wso2.org/claims. So if you want to do this for API Manager either u need to install claim management feature or go to database level and manually change claims in UM_CLAIM table.

Comment: Thanks, may I also install the WSO2 Identity Server and have WSO2 API Manager rely on that install?

Comment: Yes that should work. But the problem is for latest API Manager versions there is no compatible claim management features available. So you may have to wait for next release. As a workaround you can use Identity Server sepereately and point its user store to the same user store which api manger points (configured in user-mgt.xml). Then after starting Identity server you can do the claim mangement there. Since both are sharing the same user store those same claims will appear in api manager store as well.